# b2Body- LinearImpulse

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

In my 'Bricks Breaker' game, am giving impulse b2Vec2(2,15) to a b2Body (ball). At this time body reaches till the end of upper boundry of screen but speed is too fast that user not able to play properly. 
   If i give impulse as b2Vec2(8,8), speed of ball decreases but ball doesn't reaches till the end of the top.

I just want that how should i slow down the speed of ball and also it should reach to the top boundry also?

Below is the code:

```
 b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2(3,15);
 b2Vec2 pos = ballBody->GetPosition();
 ballBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(force, b2Vec2(pos));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x(t) = x0 + v.x * t; (1)
y(t) = y0 + v.y * t - g * t * t; (2)
```

If you need y(t) to be more then h - solve `(2) >= h` to find the initial vertical velocity v.y.

More simple approach:

`max_h = (v.y * v.y) / (2 * g)`

You can found the minimal `v.y` now.

Comment: Sorry but,didn't get you. Can you please explain about x,y,v and t?

Comment: x - horizontal coord, y - vertical coord. v - initial speed vector. t - time

Comment: but, how do i get the track of time?